# Custom Content Type in Drupal 7 - Where's my Title?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm programatically creating a custom content type in a Drupal 7 Module. I've followed the examples, but for some reason after installing it, the content type isn't shown under the content type list, and when creating content of the type Course, there is no spot to enter a title.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my course.install file:

```
<?php
function course_schema()
{
    $schema['course_status'] = array('description' => t('Stores user specific course status information.'),
                                     'fields'      => array('id'           => array('description' => t('The primary identifier'),
                                                                                    'type'        => 'serial',
                                                                                    'unsigned'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'not null'    => TRUE),
                                                            'uid'          => array('description' => t('The user identifier.'),
                                                                                    'type'        => 'int',
                                                                                    'unsigned'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'not null'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'default'     => 0),
                                                            'nid'          => array('description' => t('The node identifier.'),
                                                                                    'type'        => 'int',
                                                                                    'unsigned'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'not null'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'default'     => 0),
                                                            'visits'       => array('description' => t('The visit count.'),
                                                                                    'type'        => 'int',
                                                                                    'unsigned'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'not null'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'default'     => 0),
                                                            'is_completed' => array('description' => t('The completion flag.'),
                                                                                    'type'        => 'int',
                                                                                    'unsigned'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'not null'    => TRUE,
                                                                                    'default'     => 0),
                                                            'completed_at' => array('description' => t('The completion date, as a timestamp.'),
                                                                                    'type'        => 'int',
                                                                                    'default'     => NULL)),
                                     'primary key' => array('id'));

    return $schema;
}

function course_install()
{
    // During installation, the t() function is unavailable, so we use get_t()
    // to store the name of the translation function.
    $t = get_t();

    // We define the node type as an associative array.
    $course = array('type'        => 'course',
                    'name'        => $t('Course'),
        // 'base' tells Drupal the base string for hook functions.
        // This is often the module name; if base is set to 'mymodule', Drupal
        // would call mymodule_insert() or similar for node hooks.
        // In this case, we set base equal to 'node_content' so Drupal will handle
        // our node as if we had designed it in the UI.
                    'base'        => 'node_content',
                    'description' => $t('This is a course node.'),
                    'title_label' => $t('Title'),
                    'custom'      => TRUE,);

    // Complete the node type definition by setting any defaults not explicitly
    // declared above.
    // http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_type_set_defaults/7
    $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($course);

    //Course blocks have an image, and body.
    node_add_body_field($content_type, $t('Description'));

    // Save the content type
    node_type_save($content_type);

    // Create all the fields we are adding to our content type.
    // http://api.drupal.org/api/function/field_create_field/7
    foreach(_course_installed_fields() as $field)
    {
        field_create_field($field);
    }

    // Create all the instances for our fields.
    // http://api.drupal.org/api/function/field_create_instance/7
    foreach(_course_installed_instances() as $instance)
    {
        $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
        $instance['bundle']      = $course['type'];
        field_create_instance($instance);
    }

    //Don't show submitted info on course nodes
//  variable_set('node_submitted_course', 0);
}

/**
 * Returns a structured array defining the fields created by this content type.
 * This is factored into this function so it can be used in both
 * node_example_install() and node_example_uninstall().
 * @return
 *          An associative array specifying the fields we wish to add to our
 *          new node type.
 * @ingroup node_example
 */
function _course_installed_fields()
{
    $t = get_t();
    return array('course_image'         => array('field_name'  => 'course_image',
                                                 'type'        => 'image',
                                                 'cardinality' => 1,),
                 'course_curriculum_id' => array('field_name'        => 'course_curriculum_id',
                                                 'type'              => 'number_integer',
                                                 'settings'          => array('max_length' => 9),
                                                 'cardinality'       => 1,));
}

/**
 * Returns a structured array defining the instances for this content type.
 * The instance lets Drupal know which widget to use to allow the user to enter
 * data and how to react in different view modes.  We are going to display a
 * page that uses a custom "node_example_list" view mode.  We will set a
 * cardinality of three allowing our content type to give the user three color
 * fields.
 * This is factored into this function so it can be used in both
 * node_example_install() and node_example_uninstall().
 * @return
 *          An associative array specifying the instances we wish to add to our new
 *          node type.
 * @ingroup node_example
 */
function _course_installed_instances()
{
    $t = get_t();
    return array('course_image'         => array('field_name'  => 'course_image',
                                                 'label'       => $t('Image:'),
                                                 'required'    => FALSE,
                                                 'widget'      => array('type'    => 'image_image',
                                                                        'weight'  => 2.10),
                                                 'display'     => array('course_list' => array('label' => 'hidden',
                                                                                               'type'  => 'image_link_content__thumbnail',))),
                 'course_curriculum_id' => array('field_name'  => 'course_curriculum_id',
                                                 'label'       => $t('Curriculum Id') . ':',
                                                 'required'    => TRUE,
                                                 'widget'      => array('type'              => 'text_textfield'),
                                                 'settings'    => array('text_processing' => 0),
                                                 'display'     => array('course_list' => array('label' => 'hidden',
                                                                                               'type'  => 'hidden'))));
}

function course_uninstall()
{
    // Drop my tables.
    drupal_uninstall_schema('course');

    //remove any nodes of the type course
    $sql    = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type';
    $result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => 'course'));
    $nids   = array();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $nids[] = $row->nid;
    }

    // Delete all the nodes at once
    node_delete_multiple($nids);

    //remove the content type
    node_type_delete('course');

    //and their associated fields
    foreach(_course_installed_fields() as $field)
    {
        field_delete_field($field['field_name']);
    }
}

?>
```

And I have this in course.module:

```
<?php
function course_node_info()
{
    return array('course' => array('name'        => t('Course'),
                                   'base'        => 'course',
                                   'description' => t('A course content type'),
                                   'has_title'   => TRUE,
                                   'title_label' => t('Title'),
                                   'locked'      => FALSE,),);
}
?>
```

**Solved**
Turns out the solution to both issues is to add this to course.module:

```
function course_form($node, $form_state)
{
return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution to both issues is to add this to course.module:

```
function course_form($node, $form_state)
{
    return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add an aside to this issue in case anyone runs into the problem I've had.

If you are having trouble getting the node form to show up when creating a node of your custom type, look for one minor thing: are you using a different name from your module name as your node type machine name and is the name of your hook_form() for your node type using your node type machine name or the module name?

I have a module named novel which creates a node type called novel_section. After about 6 hours of trying to figure out why the form for a new novel_section type wasn't displaying the body or title fields and after reading post after post online about how to create a custom node type with a custom module, I finally realized it was because my hook_form() was called novel_form() (like you would name any other module function) instead of novel_section_form().

All examples online of this are making the assumption that your module name is the same as your node type machine name and that's just not always the case. Additionally, no one mentions that the hook_form() needs to use your node type machine name regardless of whatever the module name happens to be.

If, like me, you have a module that does much more than just create a node type or creates multiple node types and you can't figure out why you can't get the title and/or body to show up in the new node form for your new node type, this should help.